# Is this a correct convenience wrapper for std::expected?

Tags: c++, std, std-expected

If I am writing a function that returns an [`std::expected`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected) object and potentially calls other functions that return `std::expected` objects, I find myself writing code snippets like this very common.

```cpp
struct Foo {  };
std::expected<Foo, std::string> f();

auto res = f();
if(!res) return std::unexpected { res.error() };
auto val = res.value();
// do something with val
```

So I write a macro like this that "returns" the value in case of success and the error in case of failure.

```cpp
#define CHECK(expr)\
({\
auto res = expr;\
if(!res) return std::unexpected { res.error() };\
res.value();\
})
```

I can then use it in this way:

```
Foo foo = CHECK(f());
```

I assume the lifetime of the variables in the inner scope should be as long as the assignment expression. Is this correct? Is there any situation where this could go wrong?

Comment: Be aware that your macro relies on [statement expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html), which is a non-standard feature of GCC compiler. It won't work with other compilers.

Comment: If you believe that the code works correctly, consider presenting your work (with its unit tests if you can) in a more-complete fashion over at [codereview.se].  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.  Before you do that, make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778) first, as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With this macro, you'd write functions like so:

```cpp
std::expected<Qux, std::string> g() {
  Foo foo = CHECK(f());
  Bar bar = CHECK(b(foo));
  return q(bar);
}
```

- The return type can't be deduced from this pattern
- Understanding the control flow of this code requires knowing (and remembering) what the macro expands to

I'd argue that avoidance of this pattern is what the monadic method [`std::expected<T,E>::and_then`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/expected/and_then) was intended for:

```cpp
auto g() {
  return f()
      .and_then([](auto foo) { return b(foo); })
      .and_then([](auto bar) { return q(bar); });
}
```

And in this particular case, it could be shortened even further:

```cpp
auto g() {
  return f()
      .and_then(b)
      .and_then(q);
}
```

though realistically, I'd imagine writing out the lambdas would be the more common case in actual code.

Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/vovTYfxf4